# WPF DataTemplate Run function on button press?

Tags: .net, wpf, datatemplate

Well the question says it all?
I have a DataTemplate with a button is there any way to run a function or some how tell the object that the button was pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the button a x:name and you can see that name in the button events 'sender' or e.source parameter

```
var source = sender as FrameworkElement; // Or whatever real control it is
var parent = source.parent; // Get parent control(s)
var dataContext = source.DataContext; // Get databinding context
```

Comment: Ok so far so good but that did not solve my problem :P, i get to .net code but how do i get the Object that the datatemplate is for? in my case Job